# Wix Installer PropertyRef schema validation error

Tags: xml, wix

Adding a `PropertyRef` element to my `Package` element produces an error during compilation.

This is my *.wxs file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MyProduct" Language="1033" Version="!(bind.FileVersion.MyApplication.exe)" Manufacturer="MyManufacturer" UpgradeCode="SOME-GUID">
    <PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_461_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" />
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    ...
  </Product>
  ...
</Wix>
```

This is the error produced by visual studio:

```
Schema validation failed with the following error at line 1, column 588: The element 'Product' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi' has invalid child element 'PropertyRef' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'. List of possible elements expected: 'Package'.
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/propertyref.html) of PropertyRef shows that `Product` should be a valid parent of `PropertyRef`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can be fixed by putting the `PropertyRef` element after the `Package` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MyProduct" Language="1033" Version="!(bind.FileVersion.MyApplication.exe)" Manufacturer="MyManufacturer" UpgradeCode="SOME-GUID">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_461_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" />
    ...
  </Product>
  ...
</Wix>
```